# How to condition link destination based on if a user has already submitted a form in Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I have a wordpress site that has an NDA. The user should see the NDA page on clicking menu link 'portal' on the header menu, and the user should submit it. The form was done through Contact Form 7.

Now if the user comes back and clicks on link 'portal', since that user has already signed the NDA, they shouldn't see the NDA form again, but they should be directed to another page.

How can i implement this?

Comment: Only when your Contact Form 7 stores some information in the database.

Comment: @RST yes it does. i have a contact form db. my idea is to check if the username exists in the contactform db and somehow condition the link based on that. where would i add that code and what would it look like? a sample would be great. thanks.

Comment: AsAssuming your users are logged in you can store that information to the database and then do a check whenever you need to. On the other hand, if users are not logged in you will have to use cookies to remember which computer (not user) has completed that action in the past.

Comment: @GuillermoCarone users definitely will be logged in. how do i store that info to the DB, and how do i change the header link.